# How do I use redux when a prop function is changing the state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, redux

I'm trying to wrap my head around how one uses redux in the case where a prop that is being passed into a component is supposed to be used to change the state of the application.

I have a working example [here](http://jsbin.com/bucewafuqe/1/edit?js,output).

```
let Input = ({handleChange}) => (
  <input type="text" onChange={handleChange('mySpecialInput')} />
)

let Text = ({message, color}) => (
  <span style={{color}}>{message}</span>
)

let App = ({message, color, handleChange}) => (
  <div>
    <Text message={message} color={color} /> <br />
    <Input handleChange={handleChange} />
  </div>
)

class ConnectedApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      color: 'orange',
      message: 'Hello World'
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(id) {
    return (event) => {
      console.log(id)
      if (id === 'mySpecialInput') {
        this.setState({'color': event.target.value})
      }
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <App 
        message={this.state.message} 
        color={this.state.color} 
        handleChange={this.handleChange} />
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ConnectedApp/>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

How would something simple like this be worked into using redux?

Comment: Does the second example not work?  I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @mjohnsonengr the second example was taken straight from the [simplest-redux-example](https://github.com/jackielii/simplest-redux-example/blob/master/index.js), just updated it, think I figured it out, still not rendering though.

Comment: It's probably not rendering because App is not receiving a message prop.

Comment: When you do `mapStateToProps`, you are essentially declaring a set of props that react-redux will pass to your wrapped component, e.g. App.  Your mapStateToProps only defines a single one, color.  If you pass other props to ConnectedApp, they will get forwarded to App

Comment: @mjohnsonengr I'm pretty close to getting it working, it's rendering now (updated code). I'm getting a `Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.` error in the console though.

Comment: name mangling. changeColor is defined twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code above built using redux!

[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/cayozivapa/1/edit?js,output)

```
let {createStore} = Redux
let {connect, Provider} = ReactRedux

// React component
let Input = ({handleChange}) => (
  <input type="text" onChange={handleChange('mySpecialInput')} />
)

let Text = ({message, color}) => (
  <span style={{color}}>{message}</span>
)

let App = ({message, color, handleChange}) => (
  <div>
    <Text message={message} color={color} /> <br />
    <Input handleChange={handleChange} />
  </div>
)

// Action

const CHANGE_COLOR = 'CHANGE_COLOR'

function changeColorAction(color) {
  return {
    type: CHANGE_COLOR,
    color
  }
}

// Reducer
function reducer(state = {color: "#ffa500"}, action) {
  let count = state.count
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_COLOR:
      return { color: action.color }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// Store
let store = createStore(reducer)

// Map Redux state to component props
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    color: state.color,
    message: "Hello World"
  }
}

function changeColorDispatcher (dispatch) {
  return (id) => {
    return (event) => {
      if (id === 'mySpecialInput') {
        return dispatch(changeColorAction(event.target.value))
      }
    }
  }
}

// Map Redux actions to component props
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    handleChange: changeColorDispatcher(dispatch)
  }
}

// Connected Component
let ConnectedApp = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('react_example')
);
```

Comment: Why do you bother passing down the action creator down the tree as a prop ? This just seems so wrong.

Comment: @whitep4nther which variable is the action creator? What's my alternative?

Comment: I posted an answer which is following way more the "way-to-go" ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can simply connect each of your components individually instead of using `connect()` on your top-level component and passing down the props in the hierarchy tree.

This will come way more handy.
[See a working example!](http://jsbin.com/yopimugili/edit?js,output)